# how to use temporary variables in conditional postgresql update?

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, plpgsql

I'm newbie to sql/plpgsql and trying to make an update involving conditionals; plpgsql doesn’t allow to use temporary variables the way I thought, an error appears when using any of my two variables I created. I've been told that I can't use a recently updated  column to update another one in the same update.

I created "tempc" due to the alleged limitation to update “ivafactura” in the same sentence and "tipoi" as boolean to avoid evaluating the same conditional twice.

What do I have to do to use “tempc” and “tipoi” correctly or how should I rewrite the function to run it efficiently?

Thanks in advance,

Jose

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatecosto(v_centro smallint, v_desde date) RETURNS void AS  
$BODY$  
declare  
tempc numeric;  
tipoi boolean;  
begin   
 update fletes  
   tipoi    :=  (select ivafronterizo from destinos where destinos.destino=fletes.origen)=2 and 
     (select ivafronterizo from destinos  where fletes.destino=destinos.destino)=2,   
   tempc    := kilos * case  
     when tipoi   
     then  (select costounitario2 from costosf where diaembarque>costosf.desde limit 1 desc)  
     else  (select costounitario  from costosf where diaembarque>costosf.desde limit 1 desc)  
     end,  
   set   
    costogas = tempc,  
    ivagas   = tempc * case  
     when tipoi   
     then (select pivafro from iva where diaembarque>=desde order by desde desc limit 1 desc)   
     else (select pivanac from iva where diaembarque>=desde order by desde desc limit 1 desc)  
    end          
  where diaembarque>=v_desde   
    and diaembarque<=coalesce((select desde - 1 from costof where desde>v_desde and centroemabrcador=v_centro order by desde limit 1), current_date)  
    and origen=v_centro;  
end;  
$BODY$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: what was error message? What do you mean "temporary variables"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is - you cannot use a variables for this, until you'll loop through the rows. Variables can hold scalar values, and you want to calculate `tipoi` and `tempc` **for each row**. I think in your case you could use precalculated columns, something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatecosto(v_centro smallint, v_desde date) RETURNS void AS  
$BODY$  
declare  
tempc numeric;  
tipoi boolean;  
begin
 with cte1 as (
    select
        *
        (select ivafronterizo from destinos where destinos.destino=fletes.origen)=2 and 
        (select ivafronterizo from destinos where fletes.destino=destinos.destino)=2 as tipoi,
    from fletes
    where diaembarque>=v_desde   
      and diaembarque<=coalesce((select desde - 1 from costof where desde>v_desde and centroemabrcador=v_centro order by desde limit 1), current_date)  
      and origen=v_centro;  
 ), cte2 as (
    select
        *,
        kilos * case  
          when tipoi   
          then  (select costounitario2 from costosf where diaembarque>costosf.desde limit 1 desc)  
          else  (select costounitario  from costosf where diaembarque>costosf.desde limit 1 desc)  
        end as tempc
    from cte1 
 )
 update fletes as f
    costogas = c.tempc,  
    ivagas   = c.tempc * case  
     when tipoi   
     then (select pivafro from iva where diaembarque>=desde order by desde desc limit 1 desc)   
     else (select pivanac from iva where diaembarque>=desde order by desde desc limit 1 desc)  
    end
from cte2 as c
where c.id = f.id   
end;  
$BODY$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I'm sure there's a way to further simplify your query, just need to see your schema. Also I suggest to use alias for tables, it's really hard to read complex queries without understanding which table which column belongs.

Comment: thanks Roman but I got lost on the last part, where did you get the id's?

Comment: I've used id as representation of primary key of fleutes table

Comment: ii forgot to append my tables     create table destinos
    ( destino integer primary key,
       ivafronterizo smallint )

     CREATE TABLE costosf

     (
 centroemabrcador integer NOT NULL,

       fuel smallint NOT NULL,

       desde date NOT NULL,

       costounitario numeric(9,7),
  
       costounitario2 numeric(9,7) )

Comment: CREATE TABLE iva

     ( desde date primary key,
       pivanac numeric(11,4),
       pivafro numeric(11,4) )

     CREATE TABLE fletes
     ( embarque numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
       diaembarque date NOT NULL,
       origen integer NOT NULL,
       destino integer NOT NULL,
       kilos smallint,
       costogas numeric(9,2),
       ivagas numeric(7,2) )

Comment: @user2716638 do you have unique or primary key in fletes table?

Comment: yes, fletes has a primary key on embarque, i see your point, is it in from fletes as f 
     inner join cte2 as c on c.embarque = f.embarque ?